# Sqlite query: How can handle merging and also handles when I update it

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have two sqlite tables that successfully merged using this code;

```
private static void MergeDatabase(string table, string mainDatabase, string mergeDatabase)
    {
        string SQL = "ATTACH '" + mergeDatabase + "' AS TOMERGE";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL);

        string databasePath = mainDatabase;
        string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}; Version=3", databasePath);
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);

        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        int retval = 0;
        try
        {
            retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss") + " An error occurred, your import was not completed.");
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        SQL = "INSERT INTO " + table + " SELECT * FROM TOMERGE." + table + " WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM " + table + ")";
        cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        retval = 0;
        try
        {
            retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss") + " An error occurred, your import was not completed.");
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

### [image: Senario1]

Result:

[image: Result]

---

Yes it merge but, I don't know how to handle if I just update some items on table2 like this;

---

[image: senario2]

As you can see the updated item from table2 just up.

I want something that can handle merging and also handle when I update some items on table2 it will just update on table1 not adding them.

Comment: What exactly should happen? Rows with the same ID should be overwritten, rows with a non-exisiting ID should be appended? (And missing IDs should be deleted in `table1`?)

Comment: The result should be when some items update on table2 with the same ID on table 1 it will just update the item on table 1.

Comment: Please show the table definition. Are there any indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will do what you want :-

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id||name NOT IN (SELECT id||name FROM table1);
```

This basically adds `OR REPLACE`, which will REPLACE the row instead of inserting the row upon a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint conflict.

The WHERE clause is a slightly changed to test id and name rather than just the name.

Names are based upon the examples i.e. table1 and table2.

This does assume that the ID column is an alias of the rowid and that the management of the id's keeps them in sync.